# Actionscript: Invalid JSON parse input for what seems valid

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I have the following JSON

```
{
    "extras": {
        "google.sent_time": 1502027522898,
        "custom": "{\"a\":{\"message_data\":\"\",\"message_id\":\"749\",\"message_command\":\"MESSAGE\"},\"i\":\"899ec3dd\"}",
        "from": "62572096498",
        "alert": "Read More...",
        "title": "New message",
        "google.message_id": "0:2905559%2ecccafd7ecd"
     } 
}
```

Using

```
var jsonObj:Object = JSON.parse(str);
```

Gives the error:

```
SyntaxError: Error #1132: Invalid JSON parse input.
    at JSON$/parseCore()
    at JSON$/parse()
```

I do not understand why this is, the JSON is valid.

Additional information,

The solution I have tried and works is as follows, despite the before and after been valid.

```
var clean:String = str.split("\\").join('');
clean = clean.replace('"custom":"{"a"', '"custom":{"a"');
clean = clean.replace('"}","from"', '"},"from"');
```

Comment: Essentially what you're doing is unconvert a string in `extras.custom` part of a JSON into a JSON sub-object. This means the JSON parser fails at recognizing escaped strings. Are you perchance using skyboy's JSON parser? Maybe you should try a different JSON parser in AS3.

Comment: @Vesper, yes I think that the parser is trying to parse the string custom. I am using the parser to Air 26. So I guess the question is why does the adobe parser not recognize the inner object as a string.

Comment: I think try an alternate parser, say this one https://github.com/blooddy/blooddy_crypto and check if it'll work. If yes, send a bug report to adobe, if no, really review the internals of received data. Maybe there is a quotes imbalance somewhere inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Few observations :**

- The JSON provide in `OP` is looking like a `JSON object` instead of `JSON string`.Hence, No need to parse the whole object.
- As `partialJsonObj.extras.custom` is a JSON string parse it to convert into JSON Object.

**DEMO**

```js
var partialJsonObj = {
    "extras": {
        "google.sent_time": 1502027522898,
        "custom": "{\"a\":{\"message_data\":\"\",\"message_id\":\"749\",\"message_command\":\"MESSAGE\"},\"i\":\"899ec3dd\"}",
        "from": "62572096498",
        "alert": "Read More...",
        "title": "New message",
        "google.message_id": "0:2905559%2ecccafd7ecd"
     } 
};

partialJsonObj.extras.custom = JSON.parse(partialJsonObj.extras.custom);

var jsonObj:Object = partialJsonObj;

console.log(jsonObj);
```

Comment: Great, I now understand.

Answer (score 2):

If this "JSON" is part of your actionscript it's an [Object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html), not a [JSON](http://www.json.org/).
The [JSON.parse](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#parse()) method won't work because accepts JSON-formatted [String](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html) as first parameter and you pass and [Object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html) instead.
If you load/import this script from a JSON file, the [JSON.parse](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#parse()) method will work.

```
// importing the external JSON file
function loadJSON() {
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSON);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("test.json"));
}

// converting to actionscript Object
function decodeJSON(e:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target) ;
    var jsonObj:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
    trace(jsonObj["extras"]["custom"]["a"]["message_id"]);
}

loadJSON();
```

If you want to access the "custom" value, uncomment double quotes in the JSON file:

```
  "custom": {"a":{"message_data":"","message_id":"749","message_command":"MESSAGE"},"i":"899ec3dd"},
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `str` is a javascript object already, so nothing to parse and you can simply assign it like:

```
var jsonObj:Object = str;
```

However I'd assume you need to parse and convert to object your `custom` property:

```
a.extras.custom = JSON.parse("{\"a\":{\"message_data\":\"\",\"message_id\":\"749\",\"message_command\":\"MESSAGE\"},\"i\":\"899ec3dd\"}")
```

Comment: I do not think this works because my json data is stored as a string, and so it cant be assigned to an object, as I just get an object containing the string. Hence using JSON.parser.

Comment: This question is for Actionscript.